# Add a button that holds the functionality to goback in Listview

Tags: android-listview

I wanted to add a back `Button` and when this `Button` is clicked, then the `ListView` will go one step back. Currently I am showing full directory files in the `ListView`. What I want is that whenever the user enters a file directory, there should be a `Button` which holds the functionality to go back.

Comment: You want to add this button to the `ListView` itself? Because there are several options you can choose from in order to have the functionality to go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved.

I take current path in a static variable whenever an item on list is clicked. Then this path is called on the onClick() event of the Back button.